# Inkscape jpg --> svg *commandline* conversion (tracepath)

Tags: command-line, svg, inkscape

I have a bunch of jpg images which I can manually convert successfully to .svg using certain settings in Inkscape. But I'd like to run batch conversion from commandline.

Is it possible to manipulate the following settings via commandline ? :

```
Path / Trace path / Mode    - (x) Grays              Scans:    [2   ]   

Path / Trace path / Mode    - [ ] Smooth
Path / Trace path / Mode    - [x] Stack scans
Path / Trace path / Mode    - [x] Remove background

Path / Trace path / Options - [x] Suppress speckles, Size:     [2   ]
Path / Trace path / Options - [x] Smooth corners,    Threshold [0.10]
Path / Trace path / Options - [x] Optimize paths,    Tolerance [0.10]

// Something like
>inkscape.exe source.jpg result.svg --trace-path=<the_above_settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Potrace it's integrated into Inkscape but there's also a command line version:

http://potrace.sourceforge.net

http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace

Comment: This method only outputs duotone svgs. Is there a way to get the output in colour?

Comment: Not sure what the answer is here, it's been awhile since I've used this feature in Inkscape, but if you look here: http://confluence.concord.org/display/CCTR/Tracing%20Color%20Raster%20Images.html you may find what you're looking for (it's a link from the bottom of the Potrace page on the Inkscape wiki).

Comment: just as reference incase someone is interested [here is the relevant source code from inkscape tracing](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/tree/master/src/trace)